# Fancybox won't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

Not sure why my fancy box isn't working. Hoping someone can help

HTML Code:

```
<div class ="homeimage">
   <a class ="fancybox" rel="group" href ="images\image9.jpg"><img src ="images\image9.jpg" alt ="Photo by Tom Harper"/></a>
 </div>
```

Import and JavaScript Code:

```
<head>
    <title>Tom Harper - Videographer</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

The folder which contains all the fancybox files is in the same directory as the webpage. All that happens when I click the image is that the image opens in a new page because of the `<a>` tags that are now reference the image.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Yes I do it looks like this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined(anonymous function) @ jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5:8m.extend.each @ jquery-latest.min.js:2f.extend.open @ jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5:7k @ jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5:44m.event.dispatch @ jquery-latest.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery-latest.min.js:3
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg: "http://unn-w13012372.newnumyspace.co.uk/Tom%20Harper/images/image6.jpg".
Navigated to http://unn-w13012372.newnumyspace.co.uk/Tom%20Harper/images/image6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

First: Download the Fancybox plugin [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license)

secondly: unzip fancybox plugin and implement into your header.
exp...: link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen"  "fancybox" is my 
unpacked plugin directory.

thirdly: Follow this [Documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples) or just copy and paste HTML and JavaScript part.

and it will work.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#single_1").fancybox({
          helpers: {
              title : {
                  type : 'float'
              }
          }
      });
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tom Harper - Videographer</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
     <!-- Add jQuery library -->
     <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
     <!-- Add fancyBox -->
     <!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#single_1").fancybox({
      helpers: {
          title : {
              type : 'float'
          }
      }
   });
  });
  </script>
  <body>
    <a id="single_1" href="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1661/24170619595_ca34ef74d9_b.jpg" title="Bos 3 (p.vanhaastrecht)">
    <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1661/24170619595_ca34ef74d9_m.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```